# When hovering effect other element

Tags: html, css

I have an input field with an svg on the left. When hovering the input field both `at` (svg) and `.input-field` should `scale(1.04);`. However, only `.input-field` does.

I tried to add `~`, `+` and only  `.at` to the hovering css but it's not working either:

```
.input-field:hover + .at {
    transform: scale(1.04);
}
```

So here is the code:

```css
.icon-container {
    position: relative;
}
.at {
    position: absolute;
    height: 20px;
        z-index: 1;
}
.input-field {
    box-sizing: border-box;
        padding-left: 38px;
}


.input-field:hover {
    transform: scale(1.04);
}
```

```html
<div class="icon-container">
    <img class="at" src="img/icons/at.svg">
    <input class="input-field" placeholder="E-Mail">  
</div>
```

Comment: Don't target the hover on the contents, use the `icon-container` for the hover - so `.icon-container: hover * {your styles here}`.